# Assetic not found in Symfony 2.8 and 3.0

Tags: symfony

I am starting a new Symfony project. After I type:

```
symfony new project-name
```

I see that the new project is created but I don't find the **Assetic** bundle inside the project. Also if I try:

```
app/console
```

I don't find the following commands:

```
assetic:dump
assetic:watch
```

Could somebody help me? What am I doing wrong. Is something wrong with the files I download?

Answer (score 12):

The Assetic Bundle isn't included since SF 3.2. I think this is caused by some compatibility issues.

You can add them manually to your composer.json

```
"symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2",
```

And add the new Bundle to your Kernel.

```
new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
```

Then it should work. I use SF 2.8 and its working. There are some deprecation warnings and i don't know if its working under SF3.

Comment: Interesting, I didn’t know that. Do you have an online resource with more information about this decision?

Comment: No unfortunately not i had the same problem as i have upgrade to SF 2.8 and copied the composer dependencies. Then i have checked that and created a new project and have seen that its missing. I don't know why.

Comment: Saddest part is that the documentation still talks of assetic commands but they do not work. Even in Symfony 3 documentation!

Comment: Yes i know its a problem i use a css and js minifier and that wasn't working anymore. So i've added that manually. Perhaps someone can look at Github if there are some informations.

Comment: Assetic version 2.7 will work fine with 2.8/3.0.  Assetic processing can be better done by things like webpack or node.  Hence the decision to remove in 3.0.  The 2.8 removal is a bit puzzling but as mentioned above: composer require symfony/assetic-bundle and updating the kernel will get you going.

Comment: And the upgrade-2.8.md file mentions it as well.

Comment: Here's a [link](https://twitter.com/fabpot/status/648520881145253888) to a Twitter discussion on retaining Assetic in Symfony or not.

Comment: Ok then the result of the discussion was to don't include it? :D Hmm... what is the actual solution to minify css and js files? Include assetic if needed?

Comment: @Cerad, I see no mention of assetic in the [upgrade-2.8](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/UPGRADE-2.8.md) file.

Comment: Mine says: "Assetic is not included by default anymore"

Comment: Now this is something interesting that came up. When I use Symfony 2.8 and Assetic 2.7 within PhpStorm, PhpStorm throws an exception. I would assume this is because the Symfony plugin for PhpStorm has not been updated for Symfony 2.8 and 3.

Comment: This is the full discussion behind this decision: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/pull/860

Comment: Thank you @JavierEguiluz is it possible to minify css and js files with the build in asset functions? That are 2 different bundles so is there a documentation for the Symfony integrated version? In most cases the documentation use the AsseticBundle and that is a bit confusing.

Comment: No, you can't minify assets with the "asset()" function (which is related to the Asset component). What you probably want to use is the AsseticBundle as explained in this article: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/php.html

Answer (score 9):

AsseticBundle was only removed from the standard distribution in 2.8. This means that if you wish to use Assetic, you may still do so, by including the dependency manually, by running:

```
composer require symfony/assetic-bundle
```

And adding the bundle in your AppKernel:

```
new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
```

One thing to know, though. AsseticBundle has not yet been migrated to 3.0.

Thus, you won't be able to use it (for now) if you wish to start a 3.0 project.
That's also the case for quite a few bundles (and among them the Sonata bundles), and even though some developers have started work on migrating to 3.0 release before the official release, last week, some bundles still need quite a lot work to be made compatible with 3.0.

Hopefully, AsseticBundle (and other) should be migrated over the next months. Or if you're impatient, you can still contribute to Assetic, or AsseticBundle! ;)

Edit: AsseticBundle should be tagged by the end of the month, if not before, as stof said in this issue: https://github.com/symfony/assetic-bundle/issues/401

Comment: Just to let people know that there're alternatives to assetic. Using gulp as asset pipeline IMHO is much more flexible and powerful. (And file watcher is much faster and smoother, no need to pollute html with huge `{% stylesheets%}` and `{%javascripts%}`  tags, it is faster. Works with heroku (adding second buildpack for node-js) and Ryan Weaver has great guide on how to set it up https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/gulp  So for new projects I would recommend gulp based workflow. HTH