# Symfony 2.8: ResourceInterface::isFresh() is deprecated since 2.8

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

After upgrading to Symfony to 2.8, I found a lot of deprecation warning:

> The class "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\Config\AsseticResource" is
>   performing resource checking through ResourceInterface::isFresh(),
>   which is deprecated since 2.8 and will be removed in 3.0 (54 times)

Stack (from Symfony profiler)

```
BCResourceInterfaceChecker::isFresh() (called from bootstrap.php.cache at line 3061)
ResourceCheckerConfigCache::isFresh() (called from ResourceCheckerConfigCacheFactory.php at line 45)
ResourceCheckerConfigCacheFactory::cache() (called from classes.php at line 1328)
Router::getMatcher() (called from classes.php at line 1288)
Router::match() (called from classes.php at line 7170)
Router::match() (called from classes.php at line 2086)
RouterListener::onKernelRequest()
call_user_func() (called from WrappedListener.php at line 61)
WrappedListener::__invoke()
call_user_func() (called from classes.php at line 1853)
EventDispatcher::doDispatch() (called from classes.php at line 1771)
EventDispatcher::dispatch() (called from TraceableEventDispatcher.php at line 132)
TraceableEventDispatcher::dispatch() (called from bootstrap.php.cache at line 3178)
HttpKernel::handleRaw() (called from bootstrap.php.cache at line 3151)
HttpKernel::handle() (called from bootstrap.php.cache at line 3302)
ContainerAwareHttpKernel::handle() (called from bootstrap.php.cache at line 2498)
Kernel::handle() (called from app_dev.php at line 29)
```

for upgrade I have used:

```
composer.phar update symfony/symfony --with-dependencies
```

this is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "framework/symfony",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "type": "project",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        }
    }
}
```

how do solve this deprecation warning?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34105114/assetic-not-found-in-symfony-2-8-and-3-0

Comment: @Matteo not solve my problem...

Comment: from symfony 2.7 on, assetic is not shipped within the framework itself anymore. i created a fresh instance of version 3, it uses some sort of asset management but not assetic anymore. maybe some maintainer could help.. update: look at this post, maybe there are some infors: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-the-new-asset-component

Comment: https://github.com/symfony/assetic-bundle/pull/395
Fix is ready to be merged, but don't know why it isn't yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some googling found this: https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony3-upgrade/fix-deprecations-in-bundles

They link to the Assetic GitHub page which claims that 2.7.1 is ready for Symfony 3. But clearly it isn't. It's that easy. Assetic just isn't symfony 3 ready so it generates a lot deprecation notices in 2.8. The [merge request to fix this](https://github.com/symfony/assetic-bundle/pull/395) hasn't been merged yet.

Answer (score 9):

The dev-master branch has been Symfony 3 compatible for a few weeks now. There is nothing wrong in updating to use it.

composer.json

```
....
"symfony/assetic-bundle": "dev-master",
....
```

composer update symfony/assetic-bundle

All errors go away.

Comment: What version do you pick up with that, if today, the 2.7.1 is the latest one and 2.7.1 has a problem? Looks like I'm missing something.

Comment: You'll pick up the version that is actively being developed (hence the tag dev-master), the version that is consistently having new features added to it (and removing depreciation code) but that has not yet been thoroughly tested for compatibility with 3rd party extensions. Normally, the dev-master is very stable but since people don't have time to always test it, it takes a very long time to move to stable yet it will solve your problems now.

Comment: Tnx @Don, I always presumed (wrongly) that dev-master would point me to the latest stable release (like 2.7.1 in this case)

Comment: @userfuser anytime :) It's a common misconception.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating the assetic bundle version to the latest one ?

```
"symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.7",
```

Comment: Will be Ok when the 2.7.2 tag will be published, It is not the case for now 31 dec 2015: check out https://github.com/symfony/assetic-bundle/issues/401

Comment: 2.7.1 isn't 3.0 compatible yet, but there is no 2.8 or 2.7.2 yet.